# how to load *.csv file as dataframe with columns with sequential numbering?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to load a csv file as a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# loading csv files

map1 = pd.read_csv('data001.csv')

print(map1)
```

However, the dataframe's column names are provided from the first's row *.csv file values. Any ideas how can I obtain a dataframe with column names that are sequentially numbered instead?

Thanks!

Comment: read_csv documentation has information about header parameter. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: `map1 = pd.read_csv('data001.csv', header=None)`

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It worked great!

Answer (score 2):

This will work. It won't read in the header, giving you numbered columns and then it skips the header.

```
import pandas as pd    
map1 = pd.read_csv('data001.csv', header=None, skiprows=1)
```

Comment: I think there is a comma missing before header=None... but otherwise, worked great!

Comment: You're right. I messed that up when I changed it from my csv's name to yours. I fixed it.